# Rerunning python script after a timeout or an error

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to find a way in which I can re run my code if there is a timeout or an error.

This is something that happens if the internet connection drops - So I'd need to delay for a few seconds whilst it comes back online and try again..

Would there be a way in which I could run my code in another python script and tell it to re run if it times out or disconnects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can start your script from an other script with subprocess. It will wait for the script to complete/timeout. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can do it with `try except` block.
You can find all about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

You just make one script, that has something like that:

```
while True:
    try:
        another_script_name.main()
    except:
        time.sleep(20)
```

Of course, you need to import both time and the other script you made.
What these lines are doing is just an infinite loop, that always tries to run the main function on the other script you made, and if some sort of error occurs, the system will sleep for 20 seconds and then will try again, because it is in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about http request connection error and if you are using the requests library you can use this [urllib retry](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html)
FYI https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
Of course, other libraries will have their own retry function.

If you just want simple retry code, use the below code

```py
retries_count = 3  # hard value
delay = 3  # hard value

while True:
    try:
        ... run some code
        return or break
    except {Your Custom Error}:
        if retries_count <= 0:
            raise
        retries_count -= 1
        time.sleep(delay)
```

A Google search for "python throttling" will give you a lot of reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try-catch in an infinite loop like this:

```
while True:
try:
    # your code
    # call another python script
except:
    time.sleep(10)
```

also, you can check if the error and run whatever you need to run, depend on the error type. for example:

```
while True:
try:
    # your code
    # call another python script
    # break
except Exception as e:
    if e == 'error type':
       time.sleep(10)
    else:
       pass
```